# Setting default Context path in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat7

Is there any way to set a default context path to the WAR I am placing in Tomcat 7 ?

Example : If my war name is MyApp-1.0.1.war, the context need to be defaulted to MyApp

http://localhost:8080/MyApp/xyz

Note : I don't want to rename my war to ROOT.war

Comment: Maybe you can rename your WAR to `MyApp##1.0.1.war`, so Tomcat will recognize the version number, see [The Context Container - Naming](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming).

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
    <Context docBase="MyApp" path="">
```

for your host in your CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml